# onScroll vs addEventListenner on React

Tags: reactjs

What are the advantages between using onScroll vs addEventListener?

Does onScroll automatically call removeEventListener when the Components are unloaded?

I could not found this information anywhere in the docs, forums, or Github itself.

Thanks!

Comment: They're entirely different things..? `onScroll` is a React handler, `addEventListener` is a DOM method

Comment: onScroll is a react synthetic event. There is a section on the React website that explains a bit about what they are an why they exist [https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)

Answer (score 0):

By using `onScroll` you could leverage the [React event system](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html), it normalizes the behavior between different browsers and helps to avoid memory leaks.

But if you want to specify whether you want to attach a [passive listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Improving_scrolling_performance_with_passive_listeners) or not you'd turn to `addEventListener`. React doesn't support this option. (ref: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6436)